# Span display inline-block not working properly

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `textbox` and a validation message assigned to it. I am trying to put the validation message inline to the `textbox`, but it comes just under it. I have tried different options but none of them is working. Below is the code for the same:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 wrap">
  <span>
    <input class="mandatoryText vtooltips form-control textbox validationInput" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; border-radius: 4px;" maxlength="100" name="tradeName" type="text">
    <span class="vspan" style="display: inline-block;">Please enter Name</span> 
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text].vtooltips {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
input[type=text].vtooltips + span.vspan {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    display:none;
    font-size:12px; 
    font-family: Arial; 
    color:white;
    border-radius:3px; 
    background: #DC000C;
    width:50%;
    border: 1px solid #6D6D6D;
    line-height: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #AFB1B1;
    margin-left:5px;
    line-height:15px;

}
.validationInput,
.validationInput:focus,
.validationInput:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFE0!important;
    border: 1px solid red!important;
    height: 20px
}
.wrap span:first-child {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%
}
.wrap span:first-child:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFE0
}
```

Here is a [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/peQKJTXEaZ) for the same.

The desired output is:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use **CSS Flexbox**. Make your `<span>` a `flex` container instead of `inline-block`, just like this:

```
span {
  display: flex;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
input[type=text].vtooltips {
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
        height: 20px;
    }
    .vspan {
        /*position: absolute;*/
        display:none;
        font-size:12px; 
        font-family: Arial; 
        color:white;
        border-radius:3px; 
        background: #DC000C;
        width:50%;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #6D6D6D;
        line-height: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        /*visibility: hidden;*/
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #AFB1B1;
        margin-left:5px;
        line-height:15px;
        
    }
.validationInput,
.validationInput:focus,
.validationInput:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFE0!important;
    border: 1px solid red!important;
    height: 20px
}

.wrap span:first-child {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%
}

.wrap span:first-child .input-holder:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFE0
}

body {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-3 wrap">
  <span>
    <span class="input-holder">
    <input type="text" class="mandatoryText vtooltips form-control textbox validationInput" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; border-radius: 4px;" maxlength="100" name="tradeName"></span>
    <span class="vspan" style="display: inline-block;">Please enter Name</span> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It do work for some extent. But in the image I provided, see there is a triangle in the top-right corner of my textbox. With your solution, the triangle disappears. I need that triangle also.

Comment: @SenjutiMahapatra I've updated my answer, please have a look at it now, this will solve your problem. Just a small structure change.

Comment: @SenjutiMahapatra Its my pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

Please do below changes :

```
<div class="col-lg-3 wrap">
  <span>
    <input class="mandatoryText vtooltips form-control textbox validationInput" style="width: 70%; vertical-align: top; border-radius: 4px;" maxlength="100" name="tradeName" type="text">
    <span class="vspan" style="display: inline;">Please enter Name</span> 
  </span>
</div>
```

please refer [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/09s95BKUqK) from here :

Comment: No it does not work. Can you provide a working sample?

Comment: I referred the demo. But as u can see, the triangle at the top right corner should be on the textbox and not outside it. Can you provide the same?

Answer (score 1):

Just add below css..

```
span.vspan{
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
}
.wrap span:first-child {
       display: flex;
}
```